# Oriental violin techniques?

Tags: violin, books

I recently started to explore oriental and arabic music, and I do play some Maqams and some ornaments and slides, but I'd like to ask if there is a methodical book or some sort of overview of the various techniques on arabic violin?

BTW, I keep my violin tuned GDAE, when I wanna play higher octaves I either switch positions or make the quarter tones between strings (i.e. E[image] on A string using 4th finger).

Thanks

Comment: Just a thought: you might enjoy an erhu:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erhu  .

Comment: Thanks but exactly what I don't want. I am looking to take out the most of my current instrument, I don't even want to change its tuning, surely not getting new instruments.

Comment: What do you mean by "or" in your second sentence? "either switch positions or make the quarter tones between strings using the 4th finger"

Comment: I'm looking for books that teaches the ornaments, slides, bow dynamics etc.

Comment: Yes, I understand I just didn't understand what you meant on the second phrase. Btw, is this interesting? http://www.gswift.com/article.pdf

Comment: Although I was targeting arabic/turkish music, this article might be useful. Anyway what I meant in my 2nd phrase is, there is Maqam (e.g. mode) that the E is half-flattened, so I have to make it with 4th finger, so I'm curious whether normally the arabic players play on all scales, because on the AE strings (western tuning) I have to make the quarter-tone with 4th finger which is a bit inconvenient.

Comment: @Sergio, the link you provided is very helpful indeed! If you have more please include! BTW, I think you should post it as answer for further reference.

Comment: @Shimmy, nice it was useful. I think you should include it in your answer, there is not much references about it in internet. Maybe better to make one good answer, I have not much more to add than the link. Although I play violin professionally, those violin cultures are kind of unknown yet.

Comment: @Sergio, oh so [here](http://music.stackexchange.com/q/11648/530) is one that you might also help me with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found [this](http://thebestofhabibi.com/vol-16-no-1-winter-1997/violin/) article to be really interesting and it indeed enriched my knowledge on the subject.

Besides that, a book named ***Studies for Arabic Music*** by **Georges Lammam** is recommended in that page. I couldn't find the book on Amazon/eBay so far.

I also found a book [***A Guide to Arabic Violin Technique for the Classical Violinist: A octoral Essay***](http://books.google.com/books?id=eTSeSgAACAAJ) by the University of Miami, but I'm not sure what its contents exactly is.

Comment: Would you care to include a short summary of the article for the casual reader and in case the link goes stale?